# insert into existing temp table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have created a temp table in sql server and inserted values to it.
If the values of a particular column are null i need to fill using some values from another table. How to query this?

sample data given below.

```
select 'name' as name,3 as age,'email' as email into #tmp1 from table1
```

**Now if the column age is empty i need to insert a value to the column age to all the existing records in tmp1.**

```
INSERT INTO #tmp1 (age)SELECT age AS [age] FROM table2 WHERE name=@name
```

But it inserts a new record.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

You want UPDATE, not INSERT

Something like this:

```
UPDATE  #tmp1 
SET age = Table2.Age
FROM table2
WHERE #tmp1.Age IS NULL
AND   #tmp1.Name = Table2.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do update not Insert:

```
Update a
a.age = b.age
from
(select id,age from table where age is null) a 
inner join
table b 
ON a.id = b.id
```